# How can i split the value of a dropdown list option and pass it in two different input fields

Tags: javascript, html, django

How can i split the value of a dropdown list option and pass it in two different input fields
scripts

```
<script>
function getsciname()
    {
    ("#selectsci").change(function() {
    var sciname = (this).val().split(',');
    ("#sid").val(sciname[0]);
    ("#sname").val(sciname[1]);
    }};
</script>
```

(dropdown) select option code

```
<select id="scinameid" class="scinameclass" onchange="getsciname()">
    <option disabled="true" selected>-- Scientific name --</option>
    {% for getData in TaxonmyDistributionInsert %}
    <option value={{getData.id}},{{getData.ScientificName}}>{{getData.id}} - 
    {{getData.ScientificName}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

input box code

```
<input type="text" style="font-size: 16px"  placeholder="Shrimp Prawn ID" name="ShrimpPrawnID" 
id="sid" />
<input type="text" style="font-size: 16px"  placeholder="Scientific Name" 
name="ScientificName" id="sname" />
```

Comment: What does not work with your code?You should not place the onchange listener two times by the way, or you place it inline in html, or you add it via jquery, if you place it  two times it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You had several problems in your script. By the way some were pretty serious and showed that you didn't grasp the concepts of events. You shouldn't reattach the handler any time the function was called. I didn't really get that point. Plus when you use jQuery you should do it through the `$` object like `$(selector)`.

By the way you just need one change event handler and in my example I attached it to the element via js instead of using the inline definition (because it's not recommended that way).

```js
//on document ready
$(document).ready(()=>{
  //adds an handler to the change event on #sinameid
  $("#scinameid").change((e)=>{ 
    //this will work as long as the only comma used is for separation
    let sciname = $(e.target).val().split(',');
    console.log(sciname);
    $("#sid").val(sciname[0]);
    $("#sname").val(sciname[1]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="scinameid" class="scinameclass">
  <option disabled="true" selected>-- Scientific name --</option>
  <option value="1,Name1">Name1</option>
  <option value="2,Name2">Name2</option>
  <option value="3,Name3">Name3</option>
  <option value="4,Name//with space//4">(4) Option with spaces</option>
  
</select>

<input
 type="text"
 style="font-size: 16px"
 placeholder="Shrimp Prawn ID"
 name="ShrimpPrawnID" 
 id="sid" />
 
<input
  type="text"
  style="font-size: 16px"
  placeholder="Scientific Name" 
  name="ScientificName"
  id="sname" />
```

Comment: if <option value="1,Name//with space//1">Name1</option>.
Then output is 
Shrimp Prawn Id = 1 and
Scientific Name = Name

I want Name// Space //1 also ...

array also save spaces in $("#sname").val(sciname[1]);

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You didn't have any concrete example in your code.. you only shared the server side template looping through something I cannot see. By the way I added the case with spaces and it works as expected. Did you expect something different? Please I need you to be clear telling me how an option should look like and which 2 values do you expect to extract exactly from there. Your latest comment was a bit confused.. you said that `<option value="1,Name//with space//1">Name1</option>` should produce `['1',' Name I want Name// Space //1']` .. I'm sure you meant something else

Comment: ah probably with this: `Name//with space//1` you meant this `Name 1`. I still don't get why did you point out. It already takes spaces into account.

Answer (score 0):

Your onchange event handler for the drop down box, should be like below. Need not call the onchange inside it once again.

In your html, bind the function to your dropdown box' `onchange` event like so,

```
<select id="scinameid" class="scinameclass" onchange="getscOptname(this)">
```

```
<script>
function getscOptname(e)
    {
        var selOpt = e.value.split(',');
        $('#sid').val(selOpt[0]);
        $('#sname').val(selOpt[1]);
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you use **onchange** or jquery `.change()` method check this

### JavaScript

```js
function getsciname(e){
    var [val1, val2] = e.target.value.split(',');
    document.getElementById('input1').value = val1
    document.getElementById('input2').value = val2
};
```

```html
<select id="select" onchange="getsciname(event)">
<option value="a, b">A, B</option>
<option value="c, d">C, D</option>
<option value="e, f">E, F</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="input1">
<input type="text" id="input2">
```

---

### JQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select').change(function(e){
        var [val1, val2] = e.target.value.split(',')
        $('#input1').val(val1)
        $('#input2').val(val2)
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
<option value="a, b">A, B</option>
<option value="c, d">C, D</option>
<option value="e, f">E, F</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="input1">
<input type="text" id="input2">
```